# SAS Macro to R %sysfunc

Tags: r, sas, lag, file-conversion

I am currently working on converting a SAS script to R. As I am relatively new to SAS, I am having a hard time understanding the following statement -

```
VARS=date id sales units 
/* create lag event variable names to be used in the RETAIN statement */
%let vars_l = lag_%sysfunc(tranwrd(&vars,%str( ),%str( lag_)));
```

Here, date, id etc. are all variables present in my current data set. I understand the function **tranwrd** is used to replace a value by another value in a Character variable. In this case, it creates new items as -

```
vars_l = lag_date lag_id lag_sales lag_units
```

Am I right? What is **vars_l**? Is it a list? Or are these variables that are added to my dataset?
Also what is the use of lag before **%sysfunc** in the code below for?

```
%let vars_l = lag_%sysfunc(tranwrd(&vars,%str( ),%str( lag_)));
```

Are lagged variables created at all or just variables with no values prefixed with lag_ is created?

I don't have access to SAS or the datasets to try and check the result. Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The following code is basically creating macro variables to hold a list of variables to process. (Note: macros in SAS are mere text replacements!)

```
%let VARS=date id sales units ;
/* create lag event variable names to be used in the RETAIN statement */
%let vars_l = lag_%sysfunc(tranwrd(&vars,%str( ),%str( lag_)));
```

If you run the following code (to see what exactly is stored in `VARS` & `vars_l` macros you see the following in the log:

```
31         %put VARS::&VARS.;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable VARS resolves to date id sales units
VARS::date id sales units
32         %put VARS_l::&VARS_L.;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable VARS_L resolves to lag_date lag_id lag_sales lag_units
VARS_l::lag_date lag_id lag_sales lag_units
```

In `R` the equvialent would be the following:

```
VARS<-c("date", "id", "sales", "units" )
vars_l<-paste("lag_",VARS, sep="")
```

The second `vars_l` macro assignment is just adding `lag_` to the begining of each space delimited value in `VARS` macro variable. Since the first value does not begin with a space, if you omit the `lag_` at the begining of `%let vars_l = lag_%sysfunc(tranwrd(&vars,%str( ),%str( lag_)));` you will get the following stored in vars_l: `date lag_id lag_sales lag_units`

From the code I can see there are no variables created just yet,  but you should find a `data step` later on which does that. The mention of `RETAIN` statement in the comments suggests just that.

Comment: True. The following lines does have a merge command and **RETAIN VARS_L** Statement. But what does that mean? Four new lag columns are created but what are the cell values in these variables?

Comment: @RHelp: you really need to post the full SAS code ( with the retain statement). It depends on what what values the RETAIN varibles are initialised with. and how the assignment happens in the later part of the code.